# Exception in HWPFDocument

Tags: java

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;

...

FileInputStream fistream=null;
try {
    fistream = new FileInputStream(basedir+File.separator+filename);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
HWPFDocument document=null;
try {
    document = new HWPFDocument(fistream);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

System.out.println("Length of docment is :" + document.characterLength());
System.out.println(document.getTextTable());
```

I have imported poi jars but still it is giving an exception as `java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 1688935826934608, expected -2226271756974174256`

Comment: Judging from the Google search results, this problem with POI is typically caused by trying to open a file with a file type that is not what you are expecting.

Comment: @Stephen C  i am importing microsoft doc file.

Comment: According to the documentation, HWPF supports Word 97 to Word 2007 ".doc" formats.  Are you using one of those?